# Unable to instantiate Angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to setup a very basic login functiniolity with `AngularJS`
This is what I have:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET Application</title> 
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 

    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script> 

    </head> 
    <body ng-app ="MyApp"> 
    <script src="/Scripts/ng/ngLogin.js"></script> 


    <div id="loginBox" ng-controller="loginCtrl"> 
    <form action="/" id="userLogin"> 
    <label>User id</label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="userId" /> 
    <label>Password</label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="password" /> 

    <input type="button" name="loginSubmit" ng-click="submit()" value="Login" /> 
    </form> 
    </div> 

    </body> 
    </html>
```

`ngLogin.js`

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log)  {
    alert($scope.userId);
    $scope.submit = function () {
        var usrName = $scope.userId;
        var password = $scope.password;
        alert(usrName);
        $log.log(usrName);
    }
}]);
```

But when I click the login button nothing happens neither the alert nor anything in the console log, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a dependencies array when you register your module:

```
angular.module("MyApp", [])
```

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. **If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.**

Answer (score 0):

Missing - []

```
angular.module("MyApp",[])
```